# web application for data modeling

Tags: database-design, web-applications

I am about to start development of a web based application and we need to create a data model for that.

Is there any

- **web based**
- **free** and ready to go
- or **open source** so I can install it on my linux server
- that allows **collaboration**

application for **data modeling**?

Comment: MySQL has a built-in data modeler tool.

Comment: does MySQL built-in data modeler tool allow online sharing? or is that only local tool?

Comment: If you save the MySQL model file on a shared drive, more than one person could change it, as long as only one person at a time uses the model file.  Otherwise, you email the model file to everyone, with one developer responsible for consolidating changes to the model.

Comment: thank you. Could you update your answer with mySQL built-in data modeler tool? I would accept it as a answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [yUML](http://yuml.me/), but the web site only draws the diagrams.  You have to provide all of the detail and associative information.

Answer (score 3):

http://dbdsgnr.appspot.com/app creates everything you need. It even outputs the SQL code for mutiple database systems